# How can I achieve this type of custom Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar exactly like the image below, using Flutter.

[image: Bottom Nav Bar UI]

What type of flutter package or custom navigation bar can be used to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a package, you can simply use a `BottomAppBar` as `bottomNavigationBar` of `Scaffold`, add a `Row` inside, and add the icon buttons like this:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    child: Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 6, 0, 12),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      // your icon buttons here
    ],
  ),
))
```

Comment: Hi, i was having a problem with the bottom navigation bar, i asked the question if you could help i would really appreciate it >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71072981/flutter-have-a-line-on-top-of-the-bottom-navigation-bar-witch-goes-to-the-select